# Calling Python code from C++ shared libarary

Tags: python, numpy, boost, cmake

I'm using boost::python in a shared library plugin to run some python code.
The shared library is loaded as a plugin in run-time by my main program using boost::dll::shared_library API. i.e. my main program does not link with the shared library plugin.
My code runs on Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm linking my shared library with Python:
my_shared_lib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development NumPy REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Python3_LIBRARIES} Python3::NumPy)
```

When running the following code from my shared library I get an ImportError:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
Py_Initialize();
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;
np::initialize(); //ImportError here
```

I get the following error:
ImportError: /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyObject_SelfIter

I verified I have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so on my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

When linking my main program with Python, the program OK runs w/o the ImportError
main_program/CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Development NumPy REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Python3_LIBRARIES} Python3::NumPy)
```

My conclusion here is that loading the shared library plugin in run-time does not seem to load libpython3.8.so, while loading libpython3.8.so in the main program makes it available for the shared library plugin.

If I manually load libpython3.8.so in my shared library like this

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <dlfcn.h>
dlopen("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
Py_Initialize();
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;
np::initialize();
```

I get a different error further along the way:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 23, in 
from . import multiarray
File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in 
from . import overrides
File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in 
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime"

How can I make my shared library plugin load libpython3.8.so automatically when it's loaded?

*** EDIT ***
Using gdb I see my initial assumption was wrong. When the main app loads my shared library plugin, it also loads libpython3.8.so.1.0.
Loaded Loaded '/home/myuser/.vs/mainapp/build/plugins/libap_python_detector.so'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/local/3rdparty/hpc/5.13.0-39_AMD_EPYC/boost176/build/lib/libboost_numpy38.so.1.76.0'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/local/3rdparty/hpc/5.13.0-39_AMD_EPYC/boost176/build/lib/libboost_python38.so.1.76.0'. Symbols loaded.

So what's wrong loading numpy?

Answer (score 5):

Currently, your design of loading NumPy from a Python interpreter embedded in a shared library is not supported by NumPy. (See [Troubleshooting ImportError](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html)
. It does not cover your scenario.)

The error occurs because NumPy shared libraries were not linked hardly to the Python runtime library. (You can inspect that with **ldd**.)

But at least on Linux, you can remedy this by loading the Python runtime library manually with RTLD_GLOBAL flag like the following example. (Load the runtime library inside your main program, not inside a plugin. Of course you will want to do that only if you are loading a Numpy-dependent plugin.)

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main()
{
    ...
    // When you load a NumPy-dependent plugin, do the following just before that.
    dlopen("libpython3.8.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    ...
}
```

But I am not sure it will not be broken in the future.